# ASP.NET define input validators programmatically depending on configuration

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm writing an ASP.NET 3.5 web application. There is a rather **complex input form** (30 input controls - TextBoxes, Dropdownlists, ...).

Now, different clients use the same form in their customized application and there are **different mandatory fields** for some clients.

Now, I'd like to **programmatically create/activate certain validators depending on configuration settings**, like (I'm simplifying here):

```
ControlsToValidateRequiredFields="NameTextBox,AddressTextBox,EmailTextBox"
```

and maybe for a second client:

```
ControlsToValidateRequiredFields="NameTextBox,PhoneTextBox"
```

Is there a ASP.NET-built-in way (or a 3rd party control) to do that? I'd like to avoid defining all validators on the page and disabling them. Can I dynamically create and attach Validators to existing controls?

*Note: I'd like to validate on client-side. BTW: I'm using the ASP.NET Ajax ControlToolkit's ValidatorCalloutExtender - but it is not a must. And yes, a jQuery-based solution would be okay.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PeterBlum.com, thats all there is to say when it comes to 3rd party validation suites. Full featured client and serverside api,